# Sum not unique in R pivot table

Tags: r

I created a pivot table as below

```
library(dplyr)
Cross_LRR = filter(data_frame, data_frame$Product =="Some filter criteria")
Cross_LRR = group_by(Cross_LRR,Customer.Origin)
Cross_LRR = summarise(Cross_LRR,
                      Total_Revenue_2018 = sum(Cross_LRR$X2018),
                      Total_Revenue_2019 = sum(Cross_LRR$X2019), 
                     Total_Revenue_2020 = sum(Cross_LRR$X2020))

Cross_LRR
```

Cross_LRR : some place to store filtered data frame
data_frame : the data frame.

But the output of this code is like below

[image]

out put of the pivot table code I executed.

The question: Why are all the sum values the same. I know it is giving the total sum. but shouldn't it give the sum of each individual category in customer.origin?  what's wrong? what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Don't use `Cross_LRR$X2018`, just `X2018`. It should be `Total_Revenue_2018 = sum(X2018)` , etc.

Comment: ok it worked. now how would I get it to display the total of each column?

Answer (score 1):

Please share some of your data for a reproducible example, but this should work:

```
library(dplyr)

Cross_LRR %>%
group_by(Cross_LRR,Customer.Origin) %>%
summarise(
          Total_Revenue_2018 = sum(X2018),
          Total_Revenue_2019 = sum(X2019), 
          Total_Revenue_2020 = sum(X2020))
```

Comment: Thank you all. It worked. But can you please explain why it should have been x2018 and not cross_LRR $x2018? I am new to R.

Comment: @RLearner For convenience, the names of columns are treated inside of dplyr verbs as internal variables. After you have used a `group_by` function, the columns-variables were divided in groups. Then `summarise` calculated the sum of each group. If you pass `cross_LRR$x2018` into `summarise` R will treat is an external variable.